# installing heroku failed: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

im try to install heroku on my ubuntu 12.04
i ran this code on my terminal

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

but it fails, the following errors appeared. what should i do? 
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: No, I gave up, I just switched to windows and just installed heroku using an installer.

Answer (score 0):

try out the alternate way of installation. Using the below commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu ./'
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
```

i think this can be worked